# How can i Unit test in angular for scrollTop

Tags: jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

HTML:

```
<div>
     <a href="#" jump-to="elem__1"></a>
     <input class="elem__1" type="text" name="name" ng-model="name"ng-required="true">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$element.on('click', function () {

    var $element = $($scope.jumpTo),
    scrollTop = $element.offset(),
    scrollPosition = scrollTop.top - 80];

    $('body').scrollTop(scrollPosition);
    $element.focus();
});
```

I wanted to unit test this functionality, but i keep getting scrollTop.top errors as it is not defined.

Error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'scrollTop.top')
```

I did something like this unit test

```
spyOn($.fn, 'scrollTop').and.returnValue(234);
element.find('a').triggerHandler('click');
expect($.fn.scrollTop).toHaveBeenCalledWith(234);
```

but it seems the element does not have scrolltop.top values

I tried to put:

```
element.find('.elem__1').offset({
    top: 234,
    left: 20
});
```

But i still get the error message above.

Comment: as per jquery docs, `jQuery does not support getting the offset coordinates of hidden elements `. so is your target element hidden ?

Comment: all elements are visible